# DesignAutomationHandler debugging tool exception when working with Workshared Cloud Model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

When wanting to debug our Revit add-in using a Workshared Cloud Model from our BIM 360 server the DesignAutomationHandler throws a FileNotFoundException at line #73 DesignAutomationHandler.cs (see image) because the BIM360: path name gets mangled.  What is the proper procedure for using the debugging tool when working with Workshared Cloud Models?
[DesignAutomationHandler.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWcSp.png)

Comment: Code should not be pasted as an image. An image is difficult to read and the content cannot be copied/pasted for trouble-shooting purposes. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add the code as text.

Comment: The code as image is only for reference to line #73, if I paste the code as you suggest then I lose the line # I am referencing, the person(s) that would provide a solution to this question will already be well versed in the actual code, because they are the same person(s) that created it - please consider this as it may affect your  -1, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DA4R doesn't support the cloud model, C4R model, and other tasks that require network access currently. Please see restrictions here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/#design-automation-api-for-revit

In other words, you have to put the C4R model as a local copy somewhere that DA4R accessible as the input parameter.

Comment: Eason  1. When using the desktop debugger tool what is the location where files can be placed that DA4R can access do you know where that is, and how to instruct the Revit add-in to open a model up from that location?  2. Taking our add-in to the next step in production where is this DA4R accessible location for the web browser client, and how do we get the Revit add-in to open a file from this location. We are already opening the file pass in from the ReadyEvent handler, but we need to open a second file to extract info from using Revit API code only  Thanks,  Todd

Comment: For using local debugging tool, you must download the C4R model to your local disk, and specify the location in the VS project settings, see the video [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool#demonstration)

Comment: If the 2nd model is linked RVT, you can check the `Host RVT file with linked models` here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/

Comment: There is no `active` document as I know, but you should be able to open other RVT files from the current directory via [Application#OpenDocumentFile](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/5716f206-98ee-0490-4c6c-f0cdd6644190.htm)